# Какое ещё бывает управление в гексагональных играх?

Tags: разработка-игр, гексагоны

Клик по гексагону знаю. А какое ещё бывает управление в играх с гексагональной сеткой? На квадратной сетке можно ещё кнопками управления кареткой, wsad, цифровым блоком. Но эти раскладки управления не лезут в гексагональную сетку.

Comment: Стрелочки с направлением движения на следующую клетку. Это подходит для пошаговых игр

Comment: Вот только кнопок со стрелками 4, а направлений 6.

Comment: а сделайте 6 конопок, делов то

Comment: Вы про стандартные клавы слышали?

Comment: Например 6 кнопок `WEDXZA`, если есть вертикальная сторона | в шестиугольнике, или `3EDXSW` для горизонтальной стороны __, на цифровом блоке соответственно `489+32` (вместо + может быть 6) для вертикали или `/96247` для горизонтали

Comment: Nowhere Man, напишите это ответом, приму.

Answer (score 3):

Гексагональная сетка бывает 2-х видов:

[image: два типа гексагональной карты]

Если взять цифровой блок клавиатуры, и принять цифру "5" как центральную точку отсчёта направления, то для первого типа можно использовать цифры: 9, 6, 3, 1, 4, 7; а для второго: 8, 9, 3, 2, 1, 7 (обозначения для кругового движения, начиная с правой верхней или верхней грани).

Блок WASD так же можно расширить до матрицы 3x3 из клавиш:
Q, W, E;
A, [S], D;
Z, X, C.

Или при желании, оставить только 4 клавиши (WASD и стрелки), но такой вариант требует, чтобы две клавиши были переключателями направления (например клавиша W или стрелка вверх для гексагональная сетки на первой картинке это селектор между направлениями левого верхнего и правого верхнего), но такой вариант вряд ли подойдет для Real-time игры, он больше присущ пошаговым стратегиям...

P. S. Уверен, что это далеко не все варианты, да и можно ли считать, что они вообще чем-то ограничены?